# Causality Inference for the Influence of Paid Traffic on Organic Traffic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, causality

I work at a small mobile game development studio, and I've been asked to analyze the relationship between paid and organic traffic for a particular app. The hypothesis is that an increase in paid traffic causes an increase in organic traffic. I am also tasked with testing this hypothesis using a Bayesian approach. However, since I only have historical data where both types of traffic are present each day, I cannot use the amount of organic traffic without the potential influence of paid traffic as a prior and compare it to the amount of traffic with paid influence.
I came up with the following idea:

1. Select a country to cease ad campaigns and another to boost ad spending
2. Calculate the weekly growth factors of organic traffic for each country over the past six months and determine the best-fitting distribution
3. Synthesize future traffic data and growth factors for the duration of the test based on the previous six months
4. Discontinue ads in one country and escalate ad spending in another
5. Compare the synthesized growth factors and data for control, discontinued, and increased spending groups with observations from the experiment.
6. ????
7. Profit

How do I determine the duration of an experiment?